# Elasticsearch Bulk API : Cannot post more than one record

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-2.0

I am trying to post the following using the bulk api. I have ES 2.2.0

```
{"index":{"_index":"junktest","_type":"test"}}
{"DocumentID":"555662","Tags":["B","C","D"],"Summary":"Summary Text","Status":"Review","Location":"HDFS","Error":"None","Author":"Abc Mnb","Sector":"Energy","Created Date":"2013-05-23"},
{"DocumentID":"555663","Tags":["A","B","C"],"Summary":"Summary Text","Status":"Review","Location":"HDFS","Error":"None","Author":"Abc Mnb","Sector":"Energy","Created Date":"2013-04-25"}
```

as

```
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/_bulk" --data-binary @post.json
```

but i get

```
  {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Malformed
     action/metadata line [3], expected START_OBJECT or END_OBJECT but found [VALUE_
STRING]"}],"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Malformed action/metadata line [3], expected START_OBJECT or END_OBJECT but found [VALUE_STRING]"},"status":400}
```

why is `},` invalid? i have even tried it without the comma but i still get the error , even though i do not have a `,` !

What is wrong with my syntax?

**Edit**

I was able to get it to work by

```
{"index":{"_index":"junktest","_type":"test"}}
{"DocumentID":"555662","Tags":["B","C","D"],"Summary":"Summary Text","Status":"Review","Location":"HDFS","Error":"None","Author":"Abc Mnb","Sector":"Energy","Created Date":"2013-05-23"}
{"index":{"_index":"junktest","_type":"test"}}
{"DocumentID":"555663","Tags":["A","B","C"],"Summary":"Summary Text","Status":"Review","Location":"HDFS","Error":"None","Author":"Abc Mnb","Sector":"Energy","Created Date":"2013-04-25"}
```

is this the only way to index multiple records using the bulk api?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the documentation

> The REST API endpoint is /_bulk, and it expects the following JSON
>   structure:
>
> ```
> action_and_meta_data\n
> optional_source\n
> action_and_meta_data\n
> optional_source\n
> ....
> action_and_meta_data\n
> optional_source\n
> ```

the `document source` is optional but the `action_meta_data` is mandatory and the two are separated by new lines. 
Given these constraints  you can only speicify one record per action.

Also in the example you provided you are not passing "_id" in the meta data which would mean the "_id" is auto-generated . Probably it is intentional but just remember in case you intend to update a document you would not be able to use the `DocumentId`.

Comment: yeah i guess it is the only way. this is more useful for multiple updates on several indices i guess. i was not including the ids on purpose. thanks

Answer (score 1):

a line break after the last record is important to get it working. I solved a similar problem by adding \n (line break) at the end of last record.

e.g. This will not work :

"{ "name":"Central School", "description":"CBSE Affiliation", "street":"Nagan"}"

but this will

"{ "name":"Central School", "description":"CBSE Affiliation", "street":"Nagan"} \n
"

Answer (score 0):

There should be no line break in JSON structure , previously I was doing with this input, It was producing the above error,

```
{ 
"index" : { "_index" : "ecommerce", "_type" : "product", "_id" : "1002" 
} 
}
{ "id": 2}
```

Now it is working fine with the following input

```
{ "index" : { "_index" : "ecommerce", "_type" : "product", "_id" : "1002" } }
{ "id": 2}
{"index":{ "_index" : "ecommerce", "_type" : "product","_id":"1003"}}
{ "id": 3,"name":"Dot net"}
```